# Apps UIWebView stuck on landscape on iPad on iOS 7

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, rotation, ios7

I have an iOS 5 + app I am getting ready for iOS 7.

I have a standard TabBar based app loading in viewcontrollers, one of which loads in a webView.

This webview has a landscape and portrait mode as the app can be rotated, this works fine on all devices except iPad running iOS 7.

The issue being the webview is always displayed as landscape on iPad on iOS 7 irrespective of the orientation, iOS 7 gets rid of the 2x button that you used to get with iPhone apps running on an iPad so it is faux full screen.

The app opens in portrait mode, if I rotate the iPad everything else rotates - all other views adjust and reposition - except the html  in the webview - it is stuck on landscape.

This happens on device and simulator

The question I suppose is why? has anyone else had experience of this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting constraints on the UIWebView. In the storyboard, look for the menu icons on the bottom right, and select the one that looks like a tie fighter. Then select 'Add Missing Constraints' or 'Reset to Suggested Constraints'.  then when your View changes (orientation), the space constraints will adjust.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. All the older answers didn't work for iOS 7 (obviously..). Why have they changed the behaviour of storyboard? I hate this layout engine. But your solution worked!